# Problema no websocket qt e javascript

Tags: javascript, qt

Olá tenho um componente webview, no qt, nele eu carrego uma pagina html..
No linux funciona perfeitamente... Já no windows o websocket fica parando e iniciando e não consegue iniciar... Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver esse problema?

Edit: Rescussitando esse topico para ver se consigo resolver.
No javascript conecto ao wss com

```
    var websocket;
    function iniciaWebsocket(){
    websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { $("#view_panel").append("aberto"); };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { $("#view_panel").append("fechado"); iniciaWebsocket(); }; // reinicio
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt)
    {
      //aqui captura a mensagem
    }
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) {}
    }
```

E é isso... Não tá funcionando e isso acontece só no windows... No Linux funciona perfeitamente. Será que realmente não tem jeito de resolver poxa? Meu software que depende 100% disso não vai poder funcionar no windows só por causa desse detalhe?

Comment: Podes juntar o código que estás a usar e/ou mais informação para descrever o problema?

Comment: Pior que não faço nem ideia de como dar mais informações... Porque o websocket é algo automatico, ele tem uma key, que é gerada de forma automatica pelo site..

Comment: O probema deve ser alguma compatibilidade do javascript na webview do qt, pra windows..
Porque no qt pra linux funciona direitinho